# Why do i keep getting negative values?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, double

I am making a Leibniz algorithm in c to calculate pie. I keep getting negative result. Is it becuase of the Long Double type i used?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
int iterations;
int counter = 1;
long double nextnum = 1.;
long double answer=0.0;
long double temp = 0.0;

printf("Iterations: ");
scanf("%d",&iterations);

while (counter <= iterations)
{
    if (counter%2 != 1)
    {
        answer = temp + (1/nextnum*4);
        printf("%1Lf\n",answer);
        nextnum = nextnum +2;
        temp = answer;
        counter++;
    }

    if (counter%2 == 1)
    {
        answer = temp - (1/nextnum*4);
        printf("%1Lf\n",answer);
        nextnum = nextnum +2;
        temp = answer;
        counter++;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You start `counter` at 1, and, when `counter` is odd, you subtract a term. So you are evaluating the series −4 + 4/3 −4/5 + 4/7… To evaluate +4 − 4/3 + 4/5 − 4/7, start `counter` at 0 or swap your test for `counter`.

Comment: Incidentally, we generally do not write separate `if` statements for mutually exclusive conditions such as  `if (counter % 2 != 1)` and `if (counter % 2 == 1)`. Instead, a single `if` statement with an `else` suffices.

Answer (score -1):

You multiply by 4 in the wrong place. Try calculating pi/a as in the  [original formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int iterations;
    int counter = 1;
    long double nextnum = 3.0;
    long double answer = 0.0;
    long double temp = 1.0;

    printf("Iterations: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &iterations);

    while (counter <= iterations)
    {
        if (counter % 2 != 1)
        {
            answer = temp + (1 / nextnum);
            printf("%1Lf\n", answer);

            temp = answer;
        }

        else
        {
            answer = temp - (1 / nextnum);
            printf("%1Lf\n", answer);
            temp = answer;
        }
        nextnum += 2;
        counter++;
    }

    printf("\n Answer: %1Lf\n", 4 * answer);

    return 0;
}
```